# Can't understand sessions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please don't bit my for my misunderstanding.
The sessions are very new for me, and i have some problems.

Okay i read many information about sessions and especially rails session. But this don't give me right imagine about sessions.

Did i understand right, when users send request to server (get) -> Server create a new session (and store this some file in hard drive with session id), session id -> is a random generated num? so, server create a new session (and store session on drive) after this server send back answer to client and set session_id in cookies?

Ok, i debug some params and see some results:

## debug(session):

```
{:_csrf_token=>"jeONIfNxFmnpDn/xt6I0icNK1m3EB3CzT9KMntNk7KU=", :session_id=>"06c5628155efaa6446582c491499af6d", "flash"=>{}}
```

## debug(cookies):

```
{"remember_user_token"=>"1::3GFRFyXb83lffzwPDPQd", "_blog_session"=>"BAh7CDoQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMWplT05JZk54Rm1ucERuL3h0NkkwaWNOSzFtM0VCM0N6VDlLTW50Tms3S1U9Og9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiUwNmM1NjI4MTU1ZWZhYTY0NDY1ODJjNDkxNDk5YWY2ZCIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7AA==--348c88b594e98f4bf6389d94383134fbe9b03095"}
```

Okay, i know, what _csrf_token helps to prevent csrf.
session_id ->  is id of the session which stored on hard drive (by default)

but what is _blog_session in cookies? 
also, remeber_user_token containes my id (1::*) and what about second part, what is it?

Sorry for this stupid questions, i know what i can easy use any nice auth-plugins (authlogic/clearance/devise), but i want to fully understand sessions.

Thank you.

(also sorry for my english, this is not my native language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remember_user_token` is probably  set by your authentication plugin, it is encrypted string, which is stored in users table and is used to authenticate him. Details can vary between plugins.

Second part: you are probably using cookie based session store (it is default),

So, `_blog_session` stores your encrypted session data.
More about cookie based sessions [here](http://www.caboo.se/articles/2007/2/21/new-controversial-default-rails-session-storage-cookies) and [here](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/2/21/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cookie-based-sessions).

The name "_blog_session" is set in config/initializers/session_store.rb

It looks like:

```
# Your secret key for verifying cookie session data integrity.
# If you change this key, all old sessions will become invalid!
# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random, 
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => '_blogs_session',
  :secret      => '07fb6f0d41af4ae06aebb1696fcbb5a5398d4a08570744a4cd53ff237020c43a2022b4041d617d95bcf3f5c4601c7e6c1646eecfc157cc200e7dfedd7d7c6813'
}
```